# Is circular reference between business objects (in hierarchy) common?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, parent-child

**Linq-to-Sql** classes give both a parent a reference to a child collection, and also the child a reference to the parent (single or collection). This allows one to **"drill" in both directions**, and seems quite convenient.

Is this a design that is also appropriate to use for manually created business objects (POCOs or other) ?  In case; What would be the pros/cons, or specific situations where this would be recommended?

---

**EDIT1:**

I'm thinking mainly about logic-driven behavior; meaning not user-interaction, but like programs dealing with financial transactions, game-software, etc. What if you deal with a child entity, and then need some parameter of it's parent. It seems quite convenient, but maybe it's other parts of my coding practices that is the problem and makes me feel I need this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, bi-directional references are common and useful. They're perfectly valid in object oriented architectures. The advantages are as you point out: they help you to model your domain objects, and traverse said objects efficiently. On the negative side they can make it more difficult to understand your code as there are more paths for information to flow along.

But don't worry too much about trying to placate the RDMS gods... In all likelihood it's not going to cause an issue with your underlying data store, and, at the end of the day, you have to assume your mapping technology is going to come up with a halfway decent mapping strategy or you should be replacing it with one that does.

Comment: Cheers! Am I correct you're suggesting I should introduce these dependencies also in the database, and have the ORM take care of everything? I plan to use NHibernate (likely FluentNH), though I'm just on tutorial-level with it atm.   I really have no ability yet to judge if this is an easy or error-prone task for such ORM (?)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is really the answer you are looking for, but here's my 2 cents.

Circular referencing is a horrible database design that should be avoided at all costs.

It makes a systematic inserts and deletes of batches of records nigh impossible as the order of the operations cannot be determined beforehand and is highly dependent on the data contained in records.

An example of this would be something like:

```
class Company
{
  Person ContactPerson {get;set;}
}

class Person 
{
  Company Company {get;set;}
}
```

You literally have a catch 22 (or chick-egg problem) situation here when dealing with databases.

Dealing with it in code is not so much of a problem however.

Comment: How would this affect the database design? Are not all standard database relations represented in L2S classes with circular reference members ?

Comment: @bretddog: For tables like that, L2S will generate pretty messy stuff. But I think you really mean something else. Not really circular references, as I noted.

Comment: Yes, maybe my description can be misunderstood, idk. Cause you say "tables like that", I don't mean any special tables. I mean how you design your POCOs based on completely standard tables/relations.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing a collection of children from a parent object is something that should generally be avoided if possible. If the collection is always likely to remain small, you could probably get away with it. But if the collection is large you have to deal with avoiding performance issues.

Before deciding to add the reference from parent to child you should consider your functional requirements. It is usually possible to just do a lookup for the children based on the id of the parent. And in a lot of applications where the collection sizes are large, you might use pagination to retrieve just a subset of the full collection.

Comment: I'm thinking mainly about logic-driven behavior; meaning not user-interaction, but like programs dealing with financial transactions, game-software, etc. What if you deal with a child entity, and then need some parameter of it's parent. It seems quite convenient, but maybe it's other parts of my coding practices that is the problem and makes me feel I need this..

Answer (score 0):

For in memory entities, bi-directional navigation can be really convenient.
However, this poses issues when persisting, notably:

- Storage in an RDBMS - as per Leppie.
  For one to many relationships, the
  Parent FK is stored on the Child
  records. For one to one
  relationships, store the relationship
  to the other as a FK, but only the
  one way.
- Serialization across the wire can
  also cause major headaches.
  Typically, in a one to many
  relationship, the children are nested
  underneath the parent (relationship is preserved by hierarchy). However, if
  the child entity has a reference to
  the parent, the parent entity
  reference is typically not marked as
  serializable, due to recursion (cycles). (PreserveObjectReferences Although WCF 3.5+ has now addressed this with (IsReference = true)).

Either way, bidirectional relationship references need to be 'fixed up' after rehydrating the graph from storage / deserialization. (have a look at the code generated by Linq2Sql)

Comment: Thanks! I imagined (for database storage) that the repository would need to "add" these references when fetching an aggregate root. And when saving, it just discards it. Hence if I use NHibernate I would not map this dependency at all. Maybe this is a bit complex, I will take a look at the L2S generation as you suggest.